# Replace HP Smart Array E200i without losing data

Tags: storage, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, drive-failure

I've got a Smart Array 200i which **seems** to have some bad slots (slot 3 and slot 5). It doesn't matter what HD I put in these slots, it keeps telling me the drive is bad.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is it perhaps just something I'm doing wrong? I was under the impression that all you had to do was take out the bad drive and put in the new. Am I mistaken on this?
2. If the slots are indeed bad, can I replace the whole controller (which contains the boot drive of the OS on a raid five) without losing access to this drive's data after the swap?

On a slightly separate issue, this Smart Array has 2 SATA arrays, one with the OS and one which I believe is no longer in use. I would like to delete the second array and use the slots for the first array if the slot really is bad, but I'm not sure how to be 100% sure that it's not in use for one of the logical drives. Below I've illustrated as best I could the configuration as displayed in the *Array Configuration Utility*
I will try to lay out the configuration in text form here (my reputation not being high enough and I cannot post an image):

```
Smart array E200i in embedded slot
    SATA Array A
         [+] Logical Drive 1 (953816 MB, RAID5)
         [ ] Unused Space, ??? 
    SATA Array B
         [X] Logical Drive 2 (1907675 MB, RAID 5) - Failed
         [ ] Unused Space, ???
```

UPDATE:

Response from hpacucli:

```
Smart Array E200i in Slot 0          (sn: QT91MP3908     )

   array A (SATA, Unused Space: 0 MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (931.5 GB, RAID 5, Interim Recovery Mode)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 500 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA, 500 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SATA, 1000.2 GB, Failed)

   array B (SATA, Unused Space: 0 MB)

      logicaldrive 2 (1.8 TB, RAID 5, Failed)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SATA, 0 MB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
```

Comment: Sure, we can help. How many disks are in the server? What type of disks are they? What is the size of each disk? What operating system are you using? Is the `hpacucli` utility installed?

Comment: **Type of disks:** All SATA 7.2k Seagate disks. **Array A:** has 3 disks of 500GB each. It uses Slot 1,2, and 3 (which failed). **Array B:** was meant to have 3 disks of 2TB each, but no matter which one I put in slot 5, it showed as failed. Right now, slot 4 and 6 have 2TB drives in them but the lights are dark. I'm guessing Array B is completely inactive at the moment because of the lights. **OS:** Windows Server 2003 R2 w/SP2. **hpacucli:** it appears to have it. I found the exe in the directory _C:\Program Files (x86)\Compaq\Hpacucli\Bin_

Comment: Please open `hpacucli` and run `controller all show config` - Please paste the output into your question.

Comment: It was too long for a comment, so I added it to the initial question.

Comment: FYI, the drive in slot 3 has been tested using seatools in another computer and passed, so I don't know why it's failing.

Comment: What model server is this?

Comment: The server is an HP ProLiant ML350 G5

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the utility you had me run is showing the disk in slot 3 as a 1TB disk, but it is a 500GB

Comment: Have you powered the server off and on again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of things to check.

- Are these HP disks? Are they generic disks installed in HP drive carriers? For the 500GB drive that appears to be 1TB, if it's HP-branded, HP replace older smaller capacities with larger disks, depending on product availability. 500GB SATA disks aren't made anymore, so that could be a reason.
- It is unlikely that your controller is bad or needs replacement. Plus, being an E200i, it's on your motherboard, so it's not easily replaced. Your disks are connected to a *backplane*, so a bad slot == a bad backplane, not controller.

[image]

- Check your firmware. Old versions of HP server BIOS and RAID controller firmware have bugs. If you're on a particularly-old version of the [Smart Array E200i](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3279711&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_04d35990774a4aa99e986c3080%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) firmware, [things may not work as expected.](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6195/im-tired-of-answering-questions-with-upgrade-the-firmware-or-run-updates)

**[Here's the firmware page for your server/OS combination.](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3279711&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3DswEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)**

- If you have backups of your data and can afford downtime, [shut the machine down and remove power](https://serverfault.com/questions/352502/hp-smartarray-p400-how-to-repair-failed-logical-drive/360190#360190). Power on and follow the prompts at the BIOS array screen. If prompted, choose the F2 option to "reenable all logical drives".
- You can use the `hpacucli` tool to view the progress of RAID rebuilds as well as the point-in-time disk status.
- Smart Array controllers will perform recovery operations on one logical drive at a time. In the case of the output you've presented, "logicaldrive 2" has completely failed. Is there a chance you removed the wrong disk at some point and booted the system without heeding any of the BIOS prompts?
- An additional complication here is RAID5 on SATA disks. There's a chance your "logicaldrive 1" has unrecoverable read errors (URE). If you see the status of ["Waiting for Rebuild"](https://serverfault.com/questions/440203/hp-msa60-complains-that-new-drives-are-faulty/440213#440213) after replacing a disk, the array may not be recoverable.

Comment: Very informative, thank you! There does appear to be an update available to the firmware, this will be the first thing I try as soon as I am able. I think I will be able to schedule down-time tomorrow night.