# HP P410 "Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Failed" How to fix?

Tags: raid, hp, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I'm using HP P410 raid card with BBU with 12 x 3TB drives on RAID50

After a power outage at the datacenter, the hpacucli shows this:

**Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Failed**

However, all the disks appear to be operational:

```
     Parity Group 0:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
     Parity Group 1:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:9 (port 1I:box 1:bay 9, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:10 (port 1I:box 1:bay 10, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:11 (port 1I:box 1:bay 11, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:12 (port 1I:box 1:bay 12, SATA, 3 TB, OK)
```

I couldn't find anything about an error in the ADU report.

The server is in production and I'm scared of loosing the data because parity is not online it seems. What can I do to reinitialize parity initialization?

If I do **hpacucli ctrl slot=0 ld 2 modify raid=50**, would I loose the data or will it just restart the initialization?

Here is the complete hpacucli output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=19YJ6aWF

Here is the ADU report: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyptmea8z3qwlsq/ADU%20Report%20Viewer.html

Answer (score 1):

It takes time.

From the [controller technology guide](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00687518/c00687518.pdf):

*When you create a RAID 1, RAID 5, or RAID 6 logical drive, the Smart Array controller must build the 
logical drive within the array and initialize the parity before enabling certain advanced performance 
techniques. Parity initialization takes several hours to complete. The time it takes depends on the size of the 
logical drive and the load on the controller. The Smart Array controller creates the logical drive, initializing 
the parity whenever the controller is not busy.*

Also see: [HP ACU shows parity initialization failed on Smart Array controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/435726/hp-acu-shows-parity-initialization-failed-on-smart-array-controller)

Comment: But is a single power outage capable of obliterating the entire parity drive? The controller has a BBU protected cache, after all...